# How to add imports with Android LintFix

Tags: android, lint

I am using Android LintFix (see slide [119](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/kotlinconf2017/slides/KotlinConf+Lint+Slides.pdf) or [code examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.LintFix)) and I have managed to do fixes for the function, however it does not seem to be possible to add imports like [Kotlin @Deprecated](https://dzone.com/articles/deprecated-annotation-in-kotlin) annotation. Is it possible to do somehow or should I rely on the IDE for auto-import?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [Mark Prengemann](https://github.com/winterDroid) who indicated me the solution:

Using fully qualified names with `reformat(true)` and `shortenNames()`:

```
 LintFix.create().replace()                    
 .text("<original>").with("<correction with fully qualified entities>")
 .shortenNames()
 .reformat(true)
 .build()
```

Comment: cool solution. what about extension functions?
Saying I want to replace `.justDo()` to instead use `fun SendChannel.safelyDo()`?

Comment: it does not work for kotlin top level functions.

Comment: @Re'em, it should be possible with the `imports()` function, e.g.:
```
                        fix()
                            .name("Replace with top-level function")
                            .replace()
                            .text("oldFun")
                            .with("com.example.topLevelFun") // file name is not needed
                            .imports("com.example") // just a package of the file with this function
                            .shortenNames()
                            .reformat(true)
                            .build()
```